# How can I solve the differential equation $(5y−2x)\dfrac {dy}{dx}−2y=0$ with Exact differential method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I can solve this differential equation with Homogeneous differential method but this equation also can be solved with exact method. How can i solve this equation with exact differential method?

$$(5y−2x)\dfrac {dy}{dx}−2y=0$$

Comment: thank you so much @Aryadeva

Comment: You're welcome Kar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(5y−2x)\dfrac {dy}{dx}−2y=0$$
$$(5y−2x) {dy}−2ydx=0$$
Rearrange terms:
$$-2(xdy+ydx)+5ydy=0$$
$$-2d(xy)+5ydy=0$$
Integrate.
$$5y^2-4xy=C$$